# Looping over all input fields, some random duplicates?

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to create a slide out panel that'll act like a Table of Contents for a form that has a lot of fields. I have a loop that seems to pull in things randomly except text fields twice:

[image]

#### My code

```
var ToC =
  "<div id='sticky-anchor'></div><div id='sticky'><a href='#toc'>&#9776; Table of Contents</a></div><nav role='navigation' id='toc' class='table-of-contents'><a href='#'>X Close</a>" +
    "<ul>";

var newLine, el, title, link;

jQuery(".form-wrapper").each(function() {

  el = jQuery(this).find('input');
  elLabel = jQuery(this).find('label:first');   
  title = elLabel.text();
  link = "#" + el.attr("id");

  newLine =
    "<li>" +
      "<a href='" + link + "'>" +
        title +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";

  ToC += newLine;

});

ToC +=
   "</ul>" +
  "</nav>";

jQuery(".page-node-add-application #page").prepend(ToC);
});
```

EDIT: Looks like the duplicates are caused by the jQuery select2 plugin.

Comment: can you post your html code too, I mean the tags with class=form-wrapper

Comment: Warning: markup heavy because Drupal. http://jsfiddle.net/umszsvfj/

Answer (score 0):

I think single quotes or double quotes error, i don't know which cause you can create jquery object after append, i hope this will help you

```js
var $nav=$("<nav>").attr({
 "role":"navigation",
 "id":"toc",
 "class","table-of-contents" 
});
var $a=$("<a href='#'>").text("X Close");
var $ul=$("<ul>");
$nav.append($a);
$nav.append($ul);
//var ToC =  "<div id='sticky-anchor'></div><div id='sticky'><a href='#toc'>&#9776; Table of Contents</a></div><nav role='navigation' id='toc' class='table-of-contents'><a href='#'>X Close</a>" +    "<ul>";

var newLine, el, title, link;

jQuery(".form-wrapper").each(function() {

  el = jQuery(this).find('input');
  elLabel = jQuery(this).find('label:first');   
  title = elLabel.text();
  link = "#" + el.attr("id");
 var $li= $("<li>");
 var $aa=$("<a>").attr("href",link);
 $li.append($aa);
 $ul.append($li);
 /*
  newLine =
    "<li>" +
      "<a href='" + link + "'>" +
        title +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";
  ToC += newLine;
 */
});

//ToC +=   "</ul>" +  "</nav>";

var $divanch=$("<div id='sticky-anchor'>");
var $divsticky=$("<div id='sticky'>");
var $atoc=$("<a href='#toc'>").html("&#9776; Table of Contents");
$divsticky.append($atoc);

jQuery(".page-node-add-application #page").append($divanch);
jQuery(".page-node-add-application #page").append($divsticky);
jQuery(".page-node-add-application #page").prepend($nav);
});
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement this but I get $name is undefined.